# Performing an action in Shiny after an output is rendered

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am attempting to perform an action in Shiny *after* an output is rendered. Since I try to scroll to the output's location, it is crucial the output exists *before* I try to do so. How can I check for the existence of the output object (it is created with `renderUI`), or for the completion of the output rendering from the server? I haven't found anything online or on SO about that.

**EDIT** MWE: The silly layout is to help showcase what I want. The idea is to generate some output when clicking the button, and *then*, *after* the output has been generated, to scroll to the bottom of this output. It never works on the first generation of the output, despite using the `priority` field.

```
ui <- function(id){
    fluidPage(
        tags$head(
            tags$script(
                "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('scroll_to_item', function(button) {
                    document.getElementById(button).scrollIntoView({
                      alignToTop: false,
                      behavior: 'smooth'
                    });
                  });"
            )
        ),
        fluidRow(
            column(2,
                fluidRow(
                    div(HTML(stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(10))),
                    actionButton("create_plot", label = "Create plot", icon = icon("picture", library = "glyphicon"))
                ),
            ),
            column(10)
        ),
        uiOutput("show_output")
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session){
    show_aggregations <- eventReactive(input$create_plot, ignoreInit = TRUE, label = "Output to be displayed", {
        message(whereami::whereami())
        return(fluidRow(HTML(stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(1))))
    })

    output$show_output <- renderUI({
        message(whereami::whereami())
        return(show_aggregations())
    })
    outputOptions(output, "show_output", priority = 100)

    observeEvent(show_aggregations(), label = "Scroll once the output has rendered", {
        message(whereami::whereami())
        session$sendCustomMessage("scroll_to_item", "show_output")
    }, priority = 1)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: ou maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: I don't think you can "check for the existence (or update-status) of an output object", but you can set the "priority" (interpreted as "order of execution") via `outputOptions`. See https://groups.google.com/g/shiny-discuss/c/io9CZzwimwY for one discussion about its use. (That link also mentions `freezeReactiveValue`, but I think that is not what you need here.)

Comment: Please see [this](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3348) related Github issue.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the use of `priority` field, but unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem (see edit). getting through the GitHub issue at the moment

Comment: I also tried `freezeReactiveValue`, unsuccessfully; it just prevents any execution of the scrolling function in my case, so it makes the problem worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using R / JavaScript communication functions (`Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` and `session$sendCustomMessage`), as well as `session$onFlushed`. The latter is used to collect the value of output in interest in JavaScript  (in my case, I'm interested in any change in the HTML code of the output) *after* Shiny flushed the reactive system, which is the right timing in this case:

```
session$onFlushed(function() session$sendCustomMessage("flush_message", ""), once = FALSE) # R Shiny server
```

```
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('flush_message', function(value) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('flush', $('#show_output')[0].innerHTML);
}); // JS script
```

`Shiny.setInputValue` sends back the contents of the outputs as `input$flush` in the Shiny session. An observer invalidating on any change on `input$flush` then triggers the scrolling event

```
observeEvent(input$flush, ignoreNULL = TRUE, label = "Scroll once the output has rendered", {
        message(whereami::whereami())
        if(rv_local$scroll) session$sendCustomMessage("scroll_to_item", "show_output")
        rv_local$scroll <- FALSE
    })
```

`rv_local$scroll` is a reactive value that works as a switch set to `TRUE` when the output is updated, and `FALSE` once the scrolling has been performed; it ensures scrolling is performed only when I intend it to, and not after each flush.

Shiny app

```
ui <- function(id){
    fluidPage(
        includeScript(path = "www/myscript.js"), # The JS script HAS to be stored in a directory named www
        fluidRow(
            column(2,
                fluidRow(
                    div(HTML(stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(10))),
                    actionButton("create_plot", label = "Create plot", icon = icon("picture", library = "glyphicon"))
                ),
            ),
            column(10)
        ),
        uiOutput("show_output")
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session){

    rv_local <- reactiveValues(scroll = FALSE)

    show_aggregations <- eventReactive(input$create_plot, ignoreInit = TRUE, ignoreNULL = TRUE, label = "Output to be displayed", {
        message(whereami::whereami())
        return(fluidRow(HTML(stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(1))))
    })

    output$show_output <- renderUI({
        message(whereami::whereami())
        req(show_aggregations())
        rv_local$scroll <- TRUE
        return(show_aggregations())
    })

    observeEvent(input$flush, ignoreNULL = TRUE, label = "Scroll once the output has rendered", {
        message(whereami::whereami())
        if(rv_local$scroll) session$sendCustomMessage("scroll_to_item", "show_output")
        rv_local$scroll <- FALSE
    })

    session$onFlushed(function() session$sendCustomMessage("flush_message", ""), once = FALSE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

JS script

```
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('scroll_to_item', function(button) {
    document.getElementById(button).scrollIntoView({
      alignToTop: false,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
});

Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('flush_message', function(value) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('flush', $('#show_output')[0].innerHTML);
});
```